# How to list all the folders in a directory not beginning with character L?

Tags: zsh, ls, wildcards

I want to list all the folders which do not start with L.

```
ls [L]* ///gives all the folders starting with L
```

I would like to reverse the search and list all the folders not starting with L?

Answer (score 7):

Use `^`:

```
ls [^L]*
```

does what you're after — well, assuming `ls [L]*` corresponds to what you're after (it lists everything starting with "L", not just folders).

[cuonglm's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/341508) shows how to limit the list to folders, with `zsh`.

Answer (score 5):

What you used is called *globbing*, which can't filter directory or file in POSIX shells.

With `zsh`:

```
print -rl -- [^L]*(/)
```

If you want hidden directories:

```
print -rl -- [^L]*(D/)
```

---

POSIXLY:

```
find . ! -name . -prune ! -name 'L*' -type d
```

Comment: AFAICT, POSIX doesn't specify an algorithm. It talks about developing a list of all pathnames that match. The directory `a` is accessible by the pathname `a/`, wheres the file `a` is not (`ENOTDIR`).  It works in dash and busybox at least.

Comment: @sourcejedi, I don't understand your comment; how do algorithms relate to this answer?

Comment: @Wildcard If it specified the algorithm, you could simply run the algorithm to show whether globbing can "filter directory or file in POSIX shells." Since it doesn't, you have to interpret a less formal specification.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, `ls [L]*` (which is equivalent to `ls L*`) lists the files in the current directory that are not themselves directories and whose name begins with `L`, and lists the contents of subdirectories of the current directory whose name begins with `L`. To list the files in the current directory that are not themselves directories and whose name begins with `L`, you need to pass the `-d` option: `ls -d L*`.

To match files whose name does not begin with `L`, you can use the [glob pattern](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators) `[^L]` (which can also be written `[!L]`, for compatibility with other shells). `[^L]` matches any one character other than `L`, so `[^L]*` matches file names that begin with any character other than `L`. Since file names cannot be empty, `[^L]*` matches exactly the file names that don't begin with `L`.

Alternatively, if the `extended_glob` option is set (most users put this in their `.zshrc`), you can use the `^` operator to negate matches: `^L*` matches the file names that don't match `L*`, i.e. the file names that don't begin with `L`. This syntax is specific to zsh.

Comment: thanks for the note on `ls -d` option